# How do I use my scorestreak?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I'm confused on which key to be used to use scorestreak in Black Ops2 on PC. I have tried to check the config, but it doesn't appear to be bound to any key.

Any idea which is the default key for using the scorestreak?

Answer (score 0):

It's the number `3` on your keyboard.